# Why do I have here an infinite loop when the input is 'baab' ? (Python)

Tags: python, boolean, infinite-loop

The idea of this algorithm is to eliminate 2 consecutive letters that are the same, so I decided to do it with recursivity : if the word (chaine) has 2 consecutive letters, the boolean variable which i called doublee has to be False, and if it is the case we redo the algorithm with the new word (which is the original one but without the couples of consecutive letters). If doublee is True, then the algorithm should stop and return the edited word. And the problem is that i have an infinite loop when the argument is ('baab'). In fact, with the first attempt, 'aa' is deleted so we now have 'bb' but idk why it doesn't just redo what we did before.
Here is the code :

```
def musique(chaine) :

   L = list(chaine)
   for i in range(len(chaine)-1) :
       if L[i] == L[i+1] :
           L[i], L[i+1] = 0, 0
   chaine = ''
   for i in L :
       if i != 0 :
           chaine += i

   doublee = True

   for i in range(len(chaine)-1) :
       if chaine[i] == chaine[i+1] :
           doublee = False

   while doublee == False :
       musique(chaine)

   return chaine
```

Comment: Each recursion level has its own copy of all the local variables. Assigning `doublee` in the recursive call doesn't change it in the caller, so the `while` condition doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `while` loop. Just have each recursion level check whether there are any doubles. If there are, it calls itself recursively to remove them, otherwise it returns.

```
def musique(chaine) :

   L = list(chaine)
   for i in range(len(chaine)-1) :
       if L[i] == L[i+1] :
           L[i], L[i+1] = 0, 0
   chaine = ''
   for i in L :
       if i != 0 :
           chaine += i

   for i in range(len(chaine)-1) :
       if chaine[i] == chaine[i+1] :
           return musique(chain)

   return chaine
```

Answer (score 0):

Number 1: There should be no spaces between the colon and the end of the statement.

Number 2: When you call musique again all your arguments are in the same scope, so you are effectively reseting your program. L will be reset, and so will chaine and doublee, your program will keep doing the same thing forever.